# More than just "Some Text" onClick function() innerHTML

Tags: onclick, innerhtml

I'm trying to add a read more but the content of what I am trying to add keeps breaking my code. It's not just "some text" changed to "some other text" its a huge paragraph. Someone please help!

```
            <div id="caption">me Shakur</h2>

                <span></span>
                <h2>Mopreme Shakur</h2>
                <p id="1">To Know the Legend is to Understand the Legacy Known as “Little Mutulu,” Mopreme Shakur was bor
                n to political activist father Mutulu Shakur and mother Sharan Harding in South Jamaica, Queens. He was 
                raised in South Jamaica for most of his life with the exception of a few years as a child, when Mopreme
                 lived with his father Mutulu, his father’s wife Afeni and their children, Sekyiwa and Tupac in Harlem. 
                 Their father’s activity with the Black Panthers and his role in exposing the Cointelpro Papers that 
                 brought to light the series of FBI counterintelligence programs from 1956-1971 that were designed to
                  create dissidence and division within the Civil Rights Movement sent Mutulu into hiding and separated
                   Mopreme from Tupac and Sekyiwa.</p>

                   <button id="RM1" class="more">READ MORE</button>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" >
            document.getElementById("RM1").onclick=function(){
                document.getElementById("1").innerHTML="HERES WHERE I WANT TO PUT THE FULL VERSION WITH THE READ LESS BUTTON IN html "
                }
                </script>
```

how would i do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something as shown in the demo http://code-tricks.com/jquery-read-more-less-example/ ?

Comment: yes except for it works in the example. I <style type="text/javascript">JAVA CODE HERE</script> but it still doesn't work. But it works fine on JSFIDDLE.